# C programming - validating int input so it isn't a character

Tags: c, validation

Need to write a program to take input from a user in the form of an int and validate that what they entered is not a char from a-z.

Is there another way to do this other than:

> if((num != 'a') && (num != 'b') && (num != 'c') && (num != 'd') etc.....)
>          printf("You entered %d", num);

Comment: You should be care of the negative number which has `-` as a character ahead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  It appears that you might be able to use: `int num; if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && !islower(num)) printf("You entered %d\n", num);` (noting the newline in the output).  If the input is inherently non-numeric, the `scanf()` will fail; if the input is numeric but in the range of lower-case letters (97..122 in codesets derived from ISO 8859), then it will not be accepted.  If you're using `int num = getchar();` to read a single character, the answer is somewhat different.

Comment: Accept the answer and set thy free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to work out that it's not a character, work out that it is a digit and discard the rest using the isdigit function from ctype like below.

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

if (isdigit(num)) {
  printf("You entered %d\n", num);
}
```

But this only works on single characters which is quite useless when you read in strings.  So instead you could instead use the function sscanf.  Like this.

```
int num;
if (sscanf(numstr, "%d", &num)){
  printf("You entered %d\n", num);
} else {
  printf("Invalid input '%s'\n", numstr);
}
```

Another option is to use the atoi function.  But as I recall it doesn't handle errors and I find quite inferior to sscanf.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the **isdigit()** function provided in the **ctype.h** header file

Comment: Dang, you bet me by 30secs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the isalpha() function in the "ctype.h" header. It returns true if it is a letter. So you could do something like:

```
if ( !isalpha() )
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

[Here is a link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) to the documentation for more information.

Comment: Assuming he'd be fine with **anything** except numbers, which I kinda doubt, since he mentions `int`. `isdigit()` would be a better solution.

Comment: @Saraph I originally was going to go with using that, but I re-read the question and must have interpreted it wrong. You are correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if( (c>='a'&& c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z'))
       printf("%c is an alphabet.",c);
    else
       printf("%c is not an alphabet.",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable must be declared as an integer, not a char.

Comment: This answer wasn't very different from the solution OP originally proposed.

Comment: Theoretically, your alphabetic check could capture non-alphabetic characters. If you were on an IBM mainframe that used EBCDIC, then there are non-alpha characters between the codes for `'a'` and `'z'` — and the difference `'z' - 'a'` is not 25 in EBCDIC.  Use the `isalpha()` macro from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: @Saraph: this solution is a lot more succinct than 26 equality comparisons.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, I'm assuming OP would eventually find out about `<, >` operators.