# How can validate, so that the user can enter only positive integers

Tags: c

How can I use a single while loop to restrict entry of negative integers to the code. I have previously tried with two while loops each for the two scanf() and works cool. But I am unable to figure our how to combine them into one while loop. I have removed the two while loops I have originally used. I am completely new to this and I need some ideas.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{   
    int num, uplimit, a;

    printf("Which multiplication table do you want? ");

    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("Please enter the upper limit: ");

    scanf("%d",&uplimit);


    printf("\nMultiplication Table for %d\n", num);

    printf("===========================\n\n");


for(a=1;a<=uplimit;++a)

{

    printf( "%d X %d = %d  %s\n", a, num, num*a, (num*a % 2 == 0) ? "*" : " " );

}

{

    printf("\n* indicates even multiple of %d", num);

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if input is integer type in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c).

Comment: If you read e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you will see a table of format codes. I'm sure you can find a format which is good for reading non-negative integers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You mean %u and %x? They _do_ accept negative input. An input of -1 will give `UINT_MAX`, for example, with no error indicated.

Answer (score 3):

```
char c;

while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
scanf("%d",&num);
while (num < 0)
{
    printf("You should use positive numbers!");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

Inner while makes input buffer to clean if there were some letters in input.
Also, it makes sence to move `while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF));` into a function.

Comment: Could be a lot more improved by do whiles and other binding.

Comment: do {} while dont make it possible not to write error message if the first input attempt was correct without additional check, do it?

Comment: Well yes, but how about I enter 10a. Your code will say it's ok but the user entered 10a not 10

Comment: Ive tried it now. It wont say its ok, it will run into infinite loop in the next number - we need to flush input before reading, cause it leaves "a" in it. Fixed ansver.

Comment: `fflsuh()`is windows only. So this not yet a standard answer. As soon as it becomes one I will remove my down vote.

Comment: Now it will freeze if the buffer is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58060/discussion-between-xandrmoro-and-valentin-mercier).

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace your `scanfs` by this:

```
while(scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num < 0)
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Comment: I was going to answer this question. Thought better. You need to eat the crap, i.e. if it not a number the eat the next character. BTW -1 is harsh and I will rectify that

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did not understand where it came from :)

Comment: when you enter a char rather than a integer it will not be accepted by scanf and thus remains in buffer and next time in loop again scanf will see that char. So you need to clear it somehow

Comment: @mSatyam Thank you for pointing that out, indeed this is very important and I answered a little too fast here. I have now edited my answer.

Comment: yeah sometime i too miss it.no issues