# Integer error C

Tags: c, error-handling, int

This is what I have now:

```
int main() {
int number;
printf("Type your number: ");
scanf("%i",&number);

char code[4];
printf("Type your code: ");
scanf("%s",&code);
```

When I type anything but numbers in the first one the script goes all crazy, it just shows

> Type your number: NOTaNUMBER
>
> Type your code: THErestOFtheSCRIPT

-- Back to command line

What I want it to do is

> Type your number: NOTaNUMBER
>
> You didn't enter a number

-- Back to command line

How can I do this?

---

This is different from the said duplicate. I'm talking about C here, not C++.
C doesn't know `cin`, the answer to the said duplicate. However, an answer was found below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c

Comment: Okay, this is just no duplicate of that: C++ works totally different in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input string use

```
  scanf("%s",code);
```

or better

```
  scanf("%3s",code);
```

To check correct input for number use value returned by scanf:

```
   char ch;
   if( 1 == scanf("%i",&number) )
   {
        // use correct number
   }
   else
   {
        // clean input bufer
       while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
   }
```

Comment: Your code breaks if `getchar()` returns `EOF` it will go into infinite loop.

Comment: ok. I added checking for EOF. thanks for suggestion