# Checking if any of inputs is non integer in C

Tags: c

There is a similar question here(on which this question is based)

[Check if input is integer type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4072190/3395716) and related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072483/3395716

The difference is that in that answer only one integer is checked, but I want to check multiple numbers and then quit.

I modified the program like this,

```
//variable declaration
flag=0;
    if(scanf("%d%c", &A, &term) != 2 || term != '\n')
    {
        flag=1;
    }
    if(scanf("%d%c",&B, &term) != 2 || term != '\n')
    {
        flag=1;
    }
    if(scanf("%d%c",&C,&term) != 2 || term != '\n')
    {
       flag=1;
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {
        printf("failure\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem is, the program doesn't wait for all numbers to be inputed, rather if, say first input is invalid, it will just print `failure`.

What should I do?

EDIT:
example input and output

```
5
6
7
output:nothing
```

expected

```
input:
5
f
7
output:failure
```

what happens

```
5
f
output:failure
```

Comment: What do you mean multiple numbers? can you add a correct input example.

Comment: Maybe you need `int c; while(( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c != EOF);` between in the body of those `if`s. This will clear the `stdin`.

Comment: Put each if statement in its own while(true) loop, break from the loop only when valid input has been entered.

Comment: use `fgets` then `sscanf`, or clear stdin buffer if invalid input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if there is invalid input, the `scanf` function will *not* read the input, it will be left in the input buffer for the next input function, which in your case will fail with the same input.

I recommend you use e.g. `fgets` to read the whole line, and then use e.g. `sscanf` (or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)) to convert the string to a number.

Comment: Another alternative is to discard the remainder of the line *after* the `scanf` call, using something like: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` rather than tacking `%c` onto the end of the format string... Either way, the result is the same: user input will be discarded in this case, which is probably undesirable.

Comment: I used sscanf.How would I check if input is invalid?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Just like with the normal [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function, by checking the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: if the user types `A` and presses enter, then the first `scanf` fails because it sees the `A`, but the `A` remains in the input stream. So the second and third `scanf` will also see the `A` and fail immediately.

In general, if you need to enforce a line-oriented protocol, you should use `fgets` to read a line, and use `sscanf` and/or the `strto*` family of functions to do the conversions.

Comment: I used sscanf to do the conversion, but how would I check if input is invalid

Comment: @RegisteredUser Same as you did with `scanf`, you would `if(sscanf(buffer,"%d%c", &A, &term) != 2 || term != '\n')`. Normally, the fact that `fgets` puts the `'\n'` at the end of the buffer is a nuisance, but in your case, it's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d ...` *does* read the invalid character `'f'`, but seeing that it is not an expected part of a `int` (because of the `"%d"`), *ungets* the character, putting it back into `stdin` for subsequent reading/scanning.

So until something consumes the `'f'`, additional calls with `scanf("%d%c", ...` will not change the status of things.

Better to use `fgets()` (C standard) or `getline()` (common, but not standard) to read user input.