# How to check if user input is not an int value in C

Tags: c, loops, int

I need to check if a user input value is not an int value. I've tried different combinations of what I know but I either get nothing or random errors

If the user inputs any char  it'll raise a warning message

this is what ive written

```
#include <stdio.h> 

//C program to perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, division + - * / 

int main()   
{    
    int num1,num2;
    char alpha[30]

    printf("enter numbers:\n\n");

    printf("number 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);

    printf("number 2: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);

    // write a funcntion that when a char is entered to display an error 

    if (num1//and num2 == alpha)
        printf("error");


        else {

    printf("Rezultat: \n");

    printf("sborut im e: %d\n",num1+num2);
    printf("ralikata im e: %d\n",num1-num2);
    printf("proizvedenieto im e: %d\n",num1*num2);
    printf("ralikata im e: %d\n",num1/num2);

            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you must use `try catch` to handle the error

Comment: Select the code. Click the code button **`{}`** to format the code correctly.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi - no "try catch" in "C"

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions. You request one conversion, so the return value should be 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c

Comment: What research did you do before asking this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) has a return value for a reason.

> **1-3)** Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.
>
> **4-6)** Same as **(1-3)**, except that EOF is also returned if there is a runtime constraint violation.

Here is an example program using that information:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int inputInteger;
    printf("Please provide some input.\n");
    if(scanf("%d", &inputInteger) == 1) {
        printf("You inputted an integer\n");
    } else {
        printf("You did not enter an integer\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
1[Enter]
You inputted an integer

./a.out
hello[Enter]
You did not enter an integer.
```

**Note:** I feel obliged to inform you that `scanf()` is not the best way to get input.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430310/4520911) answer for more details.

EDIT: I changed `if(scanf("%d", &inputInteger))` to `if(scanf("%d", &inputInteger) == 1)` so that `EOF` will not output that an integer was found (pointed out by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) in the comments).

Comment: okay but how to check for two scanf like my case

if (scanf("%d",&num1)( what stays in between them) scanf("%d",&num2){
printf("stuff...")
}

Comment: @Toni03m Simply use the `&&` operator inside your `if` statement.  If you don't know how to do that, I would suggest reading [a basic book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/4520911).

Comment: Note the when `stdin` is closed (end-of file), `scanf("%d", &inputInteger)` returns `EOF` and will then `printf("You inputted an integer\n");`.  Better to use `if(scanf("%d", &inputInteger) == 1)`.

Comment: @chux Edited.  Thank you, I didn't catch that.

Comment: I inputted `4.5` and it still worked. It just set the value to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

a try/catch approach works, with casting to int the test is caught by the compiler

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin,input);
int input_value;
try {
  input_value=boost::lexical_cast<int>(input));
} catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast &) {
  // process bad input here
}
```

Comment: we are talking for C language