# How do I determine whether an input value is not a number?

Tags: c, if-statement, integer

I want to create a program that says if a number is odd or even, but if I type a letter, the program must stop. What I want to do is to create an if-statement that allows the program to understand if what I typed is a number or something else.
This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a,b;

    printf("type a number ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\n");

    if (a<0) //This is supposed to understand if what I typed is a number, but it's not correct at all.
    {
        printf("ERROR, YOU MUST TYPE A NUMBER, NOT LETTERS.");
        system("PAUSE \n");
        return 0;
    }

    b=(a%2);

    if (b != 0)
    {
        printf("it's an odd number! ");
        printf("\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("it's an even number! ");
        printf("\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()` to see whether the input could be correctly interpreted as a number.

Comment: another possibility would be to use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) which gathers the input as a string, then see if it can successfully be converted to a number using the [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) family of functions... this is more work though.

Comment: All variables are collections of bits which the processor interprets as numbers. At a slightly higher level, we say that certain numbers are codes for non-numerical data, e.g. English letters, but only in context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if input is integer type in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c)

Comment: If you were to actually check the returned value from the call to `scanf()`, it would tell the code if the input was a number or not.   If the input is not a number, then `scanf()` would have returned 0.   If the input was a number, then `scanf()` would have returned 1.   That returned value indicates the number of successful input conversions.  (note `scanf()` can also return EOF when certain problems occur or the user typed (depending on the OS) <ctrl-z> or <ctrl-d>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` returns the number of format specifiers that match, so will return zero if the text entered cannot be interpreted as a decimal integer.

```
printf("type a number ");
int converted = scanf("%d", &a);
printf("\n");

if( converted == 0) 
{
    printf("ERROR, YOU MUST TYPE A NUMBER, NOT LETTERS.");
    system("PAUSE \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Testing for less that zero will not work since -1 for example is a perfectly valid decimal integer.  Had you initialised `a` to -1, it might have appeared to work, but you could not then enter a negative number.  That said `scanf()` does not guarantee not to modify the arguments on failure ot match.

Comment: It's not totally correct, because if you enter 25lsjd scanf will return 1 and it's not a valid value

Comment: yeah. I noticed that. But it's a start!

Comment: so just test if the value after the integer is an '\n' or not like in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c

Comment: @ZiedGUESMI : You are correct, but whether a number followed by junk is an acceptable input is a design issue rather than "not correct".

Answer (score 1):

Checking if `a<0` does not work in this case, as `scanf()` either returns 0 if no integer was found, or the number of integers found. Another case is that EOF is returned if the input is reached before any conversion is occuers. Just check if `scanf()` read one integer successfully:

```
if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid number\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* else, valid integer was found */

/* other code */
```

You can also just use [`fgets(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the input string, and [`strtol(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) for more thorough integer conversion. Here is an example:

```
char number[50];
char *endptr;
int num;
size_t slen;

if (fgets(number, 50, stdin) != NULL) {

    /* removes newline appended from fgets() */
    slen = strlen(input);
    if (slen > 0 && number[slen-1] == '\n') {
        number[slen-1] = '\0';
    }

    num = strtol(number, &endptr, 10);
    if (endptr == number) {
        /* No digits found */
    }

    if (*endptr != '\0') {
        /* more characters found after number */
    }

    /* more error checking at man page */
}
```

Comment: with this code, the program returns me nothing Just blank space.

Answer (score 0):

You could read into a character buffer using format, say, %40s (assuming you buffer is 40 characters), then use strtol() to see if the token was an integer without extra junk at the end.