# How can I verify that the input value is only a positive number in C?

Tags: c, validation, input, integer

I need to check that if the user input a value, the program runs only if the value is a positive integer between [1-8] (Inclusive), but if the input value is a letter or word or not input at all (Enter), the program ask again for an input

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (){

int height;

do {
    printf  ("Height: ");
    scanf ("%i", &height);
}

while (height < 1 || height > 8);   

{ .
  .
  .
  .
```

I was thinking to add another condition "|| (or)" in the while validation, something like while "height 
be different(!=) from an integer" then do...

But I can't figure out how to check that statement in other StackOverflow questions. I hope you can enlighten me

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions, you can exploit that for your need

Comment: `scanf` is not really very useful for interactive user input

Comment: If `scanf` failed (there was no number to read), you must `fflush(stdin)`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Problem is, that this will be an endless loop. flushing stdin is undefined and does nothing on most platforms.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'd expect a logic to rescan while it fails, or the value is too low or the value is too high. Yours has an "and". We seem to be thinking differently.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie By reading it (`fgets()`/`fread()`, whatever)

Comment: My favorite consultant for getting input right: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch i'm starting in code and it will help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

use `fgets()`

```
char buf[1000];
if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (buf[1] != '\n') exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (*buf < '1') exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (*buf > '8') exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
// use *buf, maybe (*buf - '0')
```

an input of `"<ENTER>"`, `"0<ENTER>"`, `"12<ENTER>"`, `"a<ENTER>"`, `"<SPACE>3<ENTER>"`, ... will exit with failure

Comment: thanks @pmg, but I don't want to exit the program, instead I want to ask the users again and again until they type a correct value, something like that:

"Inster a value betwen 1 - 8"

Height: -1
Height: 0
Height: 42
Height: 50
Height: 4
Height: Correct!!

Comment: @JuanPabloYepes, well, put the code inside an infinite loop and replace the `exit` with `continue`. Add whatever prompt you like and a `break` when the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this answered question: 
[Check if input is integer type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c)

This question only will solve the part about being able to know is the input of the `scanf` is a number or not, which seems on of the main points. You will still have to check if the input is positive or if it's in the range you want.

Comment: Please flag as duplicate, instead of linking to another answer; or elaborate what the relevant difference is.