# Sum of array in C by user input

Tags: c

i have wrote a program to sum int array but i want if one input is string(character) then the program will give error "You Must Enter Int value".

my following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


 int main()
    {
int a[1000],i,n,sum=0;
    

printf("Enter size of the array : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter elements in array : ");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
     
    sum+=a[i];
}

    printf("sum of array is : %d",sum);     

         return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to add more details about the problem. Do not edit the question to remove the code. I have rolled back your recent edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


 int main()
    {
int a[1000],i,n,sum=0;
    

printf("Enter size of the array : ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter elements in array : ");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    //scanf() return 0 if input is not valid
    if(scanf("%d",&a[i]) == 0)
    {
       printf("error");
       return;  //or use exit(0)
      
    }
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
     
    sum+=a[i];
}

    printf("sum of array is : %d",sum);     

         return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of the problem and your solution with the code for future readers. Currently, with just a snippet of code it is very hard to understand.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Actuall OP edited the question

Comment: I have rolled back the edit. But either way, I think you should include details in your answer.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Explanation is commented inside the code.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` returns the number of successfully matched input items. So, check if `scanf()` returns 1.

Comment: i don't understand please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

create a while loop in that take user input and check that is it an int if yes then break; or continue the loop printing"Enter an Integer"  check it is int or not by int c = scanf("%d",&a[]) if c == 1 then input is Integer or it is not an integer

[Check if input is integer type in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072190/check-if-input-is-integer-type-in-c)

#include <stdio.h>

```
    int main()
    {
    int a[1000],i,n,sum=0;


    printf("Enter size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter elements in array : ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1){
            printf("you must enter a int number");
       }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

    sum+=a[i];
    }

    printf("sum of array is : %d",sum);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: can u please write the full code solution because im new in C so please.

Comment: Debashish biswas i appreciate your efforts, but i want a program in which if i enter a character input it should give an error "you must enter a int number" i think it can be done with if/else....

Comment: check the code that i have include after edit the answer. i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
int main()
 {
int a[1000],i,n,sum=0;

printf("Enter size of the array : ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Enter elements in array : ");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}


for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
     
    sum+=a[i];
}
 printf("sum of array is : %d",sum);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: 1)Read the array size and store it in the variable n.
2) Scanf function reads the entered element and store the element  in to the array as a[i] using for(i=0;i<n;i++) loop.

3) sum=0, add each element of the array to the sum value using for loop with the structure for(i=0; i<n;i++) as sum=sum+a[i].

4) After all iterations of for loop, we will get the sum of all array elements.